# NDEF intent filter does not start application in Android 6 and 7

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, intentfilter, launching-application

Hey there StackOverflowers...

I'm supporting an application that have NFC read functionalities and it needs to open the app by scanning an NFC tag. It works fine on 4.3 and all 4.X versions `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED` `intent-filter`.

So the url is like this: `http://www.example.com/nfc/NFC00000001`

And I have read almost every possible related answer about NFC intent-filter.

I am able to fetch an NFC tag via the code if the activity is opened but that's not what I need.

The NFC reader apps show that my tag is

> NXP MIFARE Ultralight (Ultralight C) - NTAG213

And that it supports

> NfcA, MifareUltralight, Ndef

Not working on *Android 6*(Nexus 4), *Android 6*(OnePlus 3) and *Andorid 7.1.1*(Nexus 6P). I don't have other Android 6 and 7 devices so I cannot test on *Android 5*.

I tried with and WITHOUT `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED`

**I tried almost every possible option and this is my final approach which doesn't work too(the app is not being launched).**

```
<activity
android:name=".activities.QRActivity"
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:pathPattern="/nfc/..*"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:pathPattern="/nfc/..*"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data
    android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
    android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:pathPattern="/nfc/..*"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

My technologies file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcBarcode</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

I also tried:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:pathPattern="\\/nfc/..*"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

And:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:pathPattern="/nfc/.*"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

And even:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

And:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/nfc"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

If someone have some advice how to make it work or give explanation why it is not possible it would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you verified that the record with the URL is correctly written to your tag? Things like character set ...

Comment: Yes when my activity is opened it reads: http://www.example.com/nfc/NFC00000001 but the app doesn't launch alone if my app is not opened. PS the http protocol is not visible in the stackoverflow lol

Comment: I understood that part. I would verify (e.g. with the app NFC Taginfo) what data is actually on the tag.

Comment: Your very last version of intent filter works for me on a Samsung S7 with Android 6.0.1.

Comment: @corvairjo hmm it's not working on OnePlus 3, Nexus 4 and Nexus 6P... I don't have other devices to test...

Comment: You did request the NFC permission in your manifest, right?

Comment: Yes cause it's working in older versions

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the issue may lie in how you are setting your `pathPattern`.

Have you tried `android:pathPattern="\/nfc/.*"` yet?

http://bluefletch.com/blog/android-nfc-reading-tags/

Comment: nice try but this one is not working too :( just tried that... I hope the problem is in the pattern or else I'm stuck with lack of functionality for Android 6 and 7